# Angular 9 Material Dialog returning undefined on close

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 9 and have a Material dialog that is set to return `"test"` on close like this:

```
<mat-dialog-actions align='center'>
    <button mat-raised-button color='primary' [mat-dialog-close]='"test"'>
        Submit
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

In my main page component, I'm subscribing to afterAllClosed:

```
  constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) { }

  OpenMatDialog(data): void {
    this.matDialog.open(
      DialogComponent,
      { data },
    );

    if( !this.matDialogCloseSub$ )
      this.matDialogCloseSub$ = this.matDialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

However, `result` always comes back as `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

I have set the dialog component in `app.module.ts` in `entrycomponents` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogComponent,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Observable` `afterAllClosed` does not return any value, because it doesn't know which dialog data it should return. You should use, `afterClosed` from the [`MatDialogRef`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogRef), which is returned from the `open` call:

```
OpenMatDialog(data): void {
  const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(
    DialogComponent,
    { data },
  );

  if( !this.matDialogCloseSub$) {
    this.matDialogCloseSub$ = dialogRef.afterClosed.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

However, considering you are using some custom global method `OpenMatDialog`, I do see some issues, but at least you know now how to get the result from a dialog :). You will have to use the dialog reference, not the dialog service.